# web application running in local machine

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, struts

developing web application :

Ide :    Eclipse helios.
jdk used: 1.6
struts frame work: 1.2
server : jboss 4.0

project runs in localhost port number 8080.

i.e, url is:  http://localhost:8080/mfirst

it works fine in presense of internet connection. If i unplug internet connection it throws error canot find action mapping and action form class.

all my tld's and jar files are refering the local location only..

any body help please..

IN JSP PAGE:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Exception in JSP: /index.jsp:21

**LINE 21 IS:**



21: html:form  name="loginForm" type="com.product.form.loginform" action="/Login.do" onsubmit="return Validatelogin(this);"
```

**IN CONSOLE IT SHOWS**

```
...........
16:28:09,031 INFO  [PropertyMessageResources] Initializing, config='org.apache.struts.action.ActionResources', returnNull=true
16:28:09,109 ERROR [ActionServlet] Parsing error processing resource path 
java.net.UnknownHostException: struts.apache.org
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source).
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1572)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.parseModuleConfigFile(ActionServlet.java:1006)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModuleConfig(ActionServlet.java:955)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:470)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:211)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4201)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:524)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:503)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
.
.
.
.
16:28:19,046 INFO  [PropertyMessageResources] Initializing, config='org.apache.struts.util.LocalStrings', returnNull=true
16:28:19,046 INFO  [PropertyMessageResources] Initializing, config='org.apache.struts.taglib.html.LocalStrings', returnNull=true
16:28:19,046 ERROR [[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find ActionMappings or ActionFormBeans collection
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.lookup(FormTag.java:798)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.doStartTag(FormTag.java:506)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_html_form_0(index_jsp.java:181)
```

Comment: Jboss 4.0 is sooooooo old. If you want to stay with JBoss 4, at least go to 4.0.5 or even 4.2.3. The problem you see may just go away by itself then.

Comment: Search for reference of "struts.apache.org" in your struts configuration files, if you find any replace it with your local location after downloading the xsd'd from struts

Answer (score 2):

There is a possibility that some of the xml configuration files you are using contain out of date references to DTDs which are no longer distributed in the jars you are using. Therefore the xml parser is trying to resolve those over the network.

This has [recently happened in hibernate](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5485) as well and I found out becase the application required an extra 5 seconds to start up.

Comment: K I'LL POST THE ERROR EDITING IN QUESTION

Answer (score 2):

Your stack trace tells the entire story:

> Parsing error processing resource path
>   java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   struts.apache.org at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown
>   Source). at
>   sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown
>   Source) at

Your application is trying to connect to `struts.apache.org` since the `XMLEntityManager` is trying to connect to this site using `HttpURLConnection`.

Solution: download the DTD you're missing and add it to your application's path so it can be locally found.

Answer (score 1):

Even I had the same problem. After thorough analysis I found that I have multiple versions of the struts jar in my WEB-INF/lib folder. After removing the version I didn't require, it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Search for reference of "struts.apache.org" in your struts configuration files, if you find any replace it with your local location after downloading the xsd's from struts